# @Html.Label ASP.NET 4 TO ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code

```
@foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId)
{
   <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value" class="checkbox-inline" />
   @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
}
```

that worked in ASP.NET 4.

However in ASP.NET 5 there is no overload method for

```
@Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
```

Result is I get a compile error

Question:

1. Must I use plain html or is there a way I can still use the HTML Helper?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this overload

```
@Html.Label("Value","Value", new { @class = "control-label" })
```

Or the `Html.LabelFor` helper method

```
@Html.LabelFor(d => item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })

@foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId)
{
   <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value"
                                                      class="checkbox-inline"/>

   @Html.Label("item.Value","Value", new { @class = "control-label" })
   <h2>Other option is </h2>
   @Html.LabelFor(d => item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
}
```

Or simply, you can write the HTML markup (*which is my personal preference*) .

```
@foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleId)
{
   <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.Value"
                                                      class="checkbox-inline"/>

   <label class="control-label" for="item_Value">Value</label>
}
```

In ASPNET5, the team introduced, Tag helpers which will allow us to write the view markup without the use of this `@Html` helpers. This allows designers who does not know C# to create view markup.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Html.Label` in ASP.NET 5 only have the `IHtmlHelper.Label(string expression, string labelText, object htmlAttributes)` interface. You can see the source code from [aspnet/mvc](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/IHtmlHelper.cs#L462)

You may need to change your code to `@Html.Label(item.Value, "Some text to display", new { @class = "control-label" })`